# w3school soap web service doesn't return the required answer

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to consume a web service by my android app. that convert between Fahrenheit and Celsius. I've created the web service on netbeans IDE (Java EE) and GlassFish Application Server, but when I press the convert button nothing happens.

Update post: I've used w3school web service instead of mine just to make sure that nothing is wrong with my namespace, soap action or WSDL URL.... now the emulator doesn't even show the UI.

Code: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tempconverter;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String METHOD_NAME2 = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editCelsius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCelsius);
        final EditText editFahrenheit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFahrenheit);
        Button buttonToFahrenheit =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToFahrenheit);
        Button buttonToCelsius = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToCelsius);
        Button buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);


        buttonToFahrenheit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

                request.addProperty("celsius", editCelsius.getText().toString());
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;


                try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //this is the actual part that will call the web service
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                    if(result != null)
                    {
                          //Get the first property and change the label text
                          editFahrenheit.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }                     


            }
        });



        buttonToCelsius.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);

                //Use this to add parameters
                request.addProperty("fahrenheit",editFahrenheit.getText().toString());

                //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //this is the actual part that will call the web service
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);

                    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                    if(result != null)
                    {
                          //Get the first property and change the label text
                          editCelsius.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
              }
        });

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                editCelsius.setText("");
                editFahrenheit.setText("");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My windows Firewall state is off.

Logcat:

[image: verbose]

[image: error]

Update: MainActivity.java  after using asynctask

```
package com.example.tempconverter;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
    private static String METHOD_NAME2 = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String URL="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmxWSDL";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                 


final EditText editCelsius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCelsius);
final EditText editFahrenheit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFahrenheit);
Button buttonToFahrenheit =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToFahrenheit);
Button buttonToCelsius = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToCelsius);
Button buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);

    class FerhToCel extends AsyncTask<String, Double, SoapObject> {         
     //Declare the version of the SOAP request
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

       protected SoapObject doInBackground(String... data){             
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

        //Use this to add parameters
           request.addProperty("fahrenheit",editFahrenheit.getText().toString());

           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           envelope.dotNet = true;

           try {
               HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

               //this is the actual part that will call the web service
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

               // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
               SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

               if(result != null)
               {
                     //Get the first property and change the label text
                     editCelsius.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
               }

           }catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();}

         return null;
         //make your network call and return SoapObject
      }//End doInBackground method

    }//End AsyncTask inner class "FerhToCel"



    class CelToFerh extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, SoapObject> {

         //Declare the version of the SOAP request
          SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

          protected SoapObject doInBackground(Double... data){
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);

            //Use this to add parameters
              request.addProperty("celsius",editCelsius.getText().toString());

              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              envelope.dotNet = true;

              try {
                  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                  //this is the actual part that will call the web service
                  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);

                 // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                  SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                  if(result != null)
                  {
                        //Get the first property and change the label text
                        editFahrenheit.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                  }

              }catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

            return null;
            //make your network call and return SoapObject
         }//End doInBackground method

       }//End AsyncTask inner class "CelToFerh"


    buttonToCelsius.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FerhToCel  c = new FerhToCel();
        c.execute();                    
    }
});

   buttonToFahrenheit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CelToFerh  f = new CelToFerh();
        f.execute();                    
    }
});

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                editCelsius.setText("");
                editFahrenheit.setText("");                 
            }
        });

}//End onCreate activity
}//End MainActivity class
```

Comment: do you see an exception ? do you see request passed through server ?

Comment: No, I don't see any exception. How can I see the request thing please?

Comment: You can use netbeans debugger and glassfish

Comment: if you mean testing the web service, then yes both operations(toCelsius and toFahrenheit) work fine.

Comment: What are you getting in logcat after hitting convert button?

Comment: sound pool error loading /system/media/audio/ui/ keypress standard .ogg and soundpool error loading /system/media/audio/ui/effect_tick.ogg

Comment: Can you add the stack trace / logcat for those errors to your question?  I feel sure that the answer is buried in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should run network operation on separate thread (AsyncTask) like this :

```
private class FerhToCel extends AsyncTask<Data, Void, SoapObject> {
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

         protected SoapObject doInBackground(Data... data) {
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);       

              //Use this to add parameters
              request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

              //Declare the version of the SOAP request


              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              envelope.dotNet = true;

              try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

              }catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

            return null;
            //make your network call and return SoapObject
         }


        protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject obj) {
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
             txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());

            //process the Soap Object returned
        }
        }
```

and on the setOnClickListener just run the asynctask

```
FerhToCel  c = new FerhToCel();
                      c.execute();
```

it worked for me so hope this will help you.

Comment: Is AsyncTask class a separate file?

Comment: I tried the asynctask, the new MainActivity.java class is in the post.It still doesn't work, what's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't work try to replace the `http://tempuri.org/` in the SOAP_ACTION and NAMESPACE by `http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/` they changed it in the site but they does not update the tutorial I guess